# Need help in handling a question with edits

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

This question got a bump when someone posted an answer: [Compiler returned error: Library crypto not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22901144). The bump brought the question back on radar. Once on radar, the question was cleaned up.

The cleanup was a pinning the question in the body to the question in the title. The OP moved the question around in the body while leaving the title unchanged. So the cleanup was a rollback and a note to the person answering the question.

The person answering the question objected because he found the question using a search engine. He stated the rollback effectively invalidated the search results, which is likely true.

To be clear, this is not an editing war. Its just about keeping the question pointed in the same general direction as the original question asked.

Should anything else be done with this question? If so, how should we proceed with this question?

Comment: The question was posted, it remained there for an year without any answers, OP edited the question, it received an answer, you rolled back the question to its initial version. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm... confused.  The question didn't have an answer yet, hadn't been updated since April of 2014, then a user comes in and answers the question, and you roll the question back, because... ?  You even edited the original question yourself, I'm not sure why there was a need to roll it back?

Comment: You edited the question a year ago **after** the OP made the change.  But did not roll it back then.  Rolling it back now is quite unreasonable.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - sorry for the confusion. Yes, the rollback should have occurred back when the edit first occurred. I missed it, and others in the community missed it. That's water under the bridge. The question re-made the radar when an answer was provided. The question now is: what should be done?

Comment: @Hans - OK, so do we change the question to fit the answer? I guess that's the only alternative. Or are there other alternatives?

Answer (score 8):

Now that there's an answer (which has even received an upvote) for the updated version, keeping the original unanswered year-old question is pretty pointless. Doubly so since the change happened only a day after the initial version, indicating that the OP was more interested in the solution to the new problem.

Assuming that the answer is reasonably correct and useful, deleting it would be dumb. Leaving it attached to a question that it doesn't match makes a terrible search result.

This is a weird situation, sure, but the way to **maximize the usefulness of the page** at this point is to forget about the original problem -- that nobody seemed to care about anyways -- and re-edit the question to its "revised" version, matching the answer. (And please remove the "Hi" while you're at it.)

Comment: Thanks Josh. So what I am interested in: what should I do to make up for my current and past mistakes. *"re-edit the question to its "revised" version, matching the answer"* - OK, I will do once a few higher member folks like yourself concur. I'm genuinely not sure of the best course of action to right the wrong....

Comment: Josh's advice sounds like the best course of action to me

Comment: I wouldn't sweat whatever minor mistakes were made, @jww; once the page is fixed it's all water under the bridge.

Comment: Based on the "-5" votes, it appears the community disagrees that the question should be further edited. I'm not taking anymore action on it. Thanks for the feedback.